# Header Not Displaying Properly

Tags: header, navbar, nav

Having a problem with the header tag showing an error when included in homepage.

[image: ecommerse header]

and here is the page I'm trying to include for ecommerce

```
<body>
  <header id="header"> </header>
  
    <footer id="footer"> </footer>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>
         $(function(){
            $("#header").load('header.html');
            $("#footer").load('footer.html');
         });
    </script>

  

</body>
```

it should look like this.

[image: header tag]

Comment: I assume that your css conflict each other. so you have different view if you see directly to header.html or including in your index.html

Comment: please include your header.html and your css file so i can update my answer